# PostgreSQL initialized version 12 incompatible with 11.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, homebrew

I am on OSX 10.12, Rails 6.0.4, `gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'`
and have lately noticed issues with postgresql on various apps, that remained frozen for a while.

A rails template from Github/Le Wagon can't even migrate :

```
rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

So I do

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres

2021-12-04 15:14:57.335 CET [1964] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2021-12-04 15:14:57.335 CET [1964] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 12, which is not compatible with this version 11.14.
```

I've just made an upgrade, and it says in the end :

```
Warning: postgresql@12 12.9_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 12.9_1, run:
  brew reinstall postgresql@12
➜  background-jobs-demo git:(master) ✗ postgres -V
postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.14
```

I've also found, according to @AdrianKlaver's comment, a repo containing  postgresql@11 AND postgresql@12

What is the best thing to do ? Upgrade version 12 ? Will `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` guarantee me to upgrade version 12, and not 13 or 14 ?

Comment: Looks like there is already a Postgres 12 instance and that it created/populated the directory `/usr/local/var/postgres`. The only other way that could have happened is if someone copied a Postgres 12 data directory from somewhere else.  You need to determine whether there is more then one Postgres installed and if one of those is 12 and then point the correct one at the directory.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've just made an upgrade, and it says in the end :

    Warning: postgresql@12 12.9_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
    To reinstall 12.9_1, run:
      brew reinstall postgresql@12
    ➜  background-jobs-demo git:(master) ✗ postgres -V
    postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.14     so I m reinstalling, hope it will resolve.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I found this repo, it's  '/' , same level of /usr

Comment: So as I mentioned there is more then one instance of Postgres installed, at least 11 and 12.  You need to find where they are located and match the correct binaries to the correct data directories.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver as I said I've found where they are located. What do you mean by 'match the correct binaries to the correct data directories' ? Can you give details in answer, about how I can do that, or an example ? Do you think launching  a postgre 12 reinstallation and restart, will it be sufficient ?

Comment: No, you will end up right where you are now. Read this [Homebrew Postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew) and this [Homebrew multiple versions](https://medium.com/keeping-code/running-multiple-postgresql-versions-simultaneously-on-macos-linux-90b3d7e08ffd).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ok thanks for your advice. And what do you mean by 'match the correct binaries to the correct data directories' ? Can you give details in answer, about how I can do that, or an example ?

Comment: Read the links I sent they will show you how. I don't use MacOS so I don't have the ability to create a test setup to create a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

I went formard, but something went wrong and I couldn't complete.
Thanks to @AdrianKlaver comments (problem due to the presence of different postgresql versions) and links : [running multiple pstgresql simultaneously](https://medium.com/keeping-code/running-multiple-postgresql-versions-simultaneously-on-macos-linux-90b3d7e08ffd) and [install homebrew-commons package](https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql).

1. Check and uninstall present postgresql:
2. Install homebrew commons and postgres versions
3. Create server-side
   BUT server can't start

What went wrong ?

```
1.    
brew list |grep postgr
brew uninstall postgresql@11
brew uninstall postgresql@12
2.
brew install petere/postgresql/postgresql-common
brew install petere/postgresql/postgresql@12
3.
pg_createcluster 12 main
pg_ctlcluster 12 main start
    
Error: /usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin/pg_ctl /usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin/pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/lib/postgresql/12/main -l /usr/local/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/usr/local/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf" -c external_pid_file="/usr/local/var/run/postgresql/12-main.pid"  exited with status 1: 
    2021-12-04 22:44:50.632 CET [76694] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.9 (Homebrew petere/postgresql) on x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2), 64-bit
    2021-12-04 22:44:50.636 CET [76694] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
    2021-12-04 22:44:50.636 CET [76694] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
    2021-12-04 22:44:50.638 CET [76694] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
    2021-12-04 22:44:50.651 CET [76694] FATAL:  postmaster became multithreaded during startup
    2021-12-04 22:44:50.651 CET [76694] HINT:  Set the LC_ALL environment variable to a valid locale.
    2021-12-04 22:44:50.652 CET [76694] LOG:  database system is shut down
    pg_ctl: could not start server
    Examine the log output.
```

Comment: This is not an answer it is another question. Copy and paste it  as a new question with a link pointing back to the question above. Then delete this 'answer' .

Comment: @AdrianKlaver absolutely, I was redacting the new answer when I saw your comment.